# How to use group in phpunit?

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

How to invoke phpunit for zendframework module group wise. I mean when you invoke phpunit then it invoke module1 first then module2 and so on.

Comment: I have configure <directory>./application/modules/</directory>  in phpunit.xml file so it invoke phpunit for randomly selected module

Comment: simply list sequential your modules like `<directory>./application/modules/module1</directory>` then `<directory>./application/modules/module2</directory>` then the other `<directory>./application/modules/</directory>`

Comment: Thanks Matto. it's working fine.  Will you help me for below problem?
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'include_once(Zend\View\Helper\Approval.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory'
end\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework-1.12.11\library\Zend\Loader.php:134

I got this error while invoke phpunit via command line though I have include this directory in include path

Comment: Hi @Yogesh  seems a classloading problem, have you specified a correct bootstrap value in your phpunit.xml files? I'm not so familiar with zend try to take a look at [this](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/zendframework-2-centralize-phpunit-test/) article.

Comment: Hi Matteo I have given  group like grp1,grp2,grp3 etc...Also I have create batch file to run phpunit where I have write command @echo off 
phpunit --group grp1,grp2 --configuration phpunit.xml and I run batch file it execute unittest group wise such as grp1,grp2,grp3. Same thing not working my another  project where it run in alphabetical order of modulename.What should be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply archive your problem simply list sequential your modules like:

phpunit.xml

```
.....
<directory>./application/modules/module1</directory>
<directory>./application/modules/module2</directory> 
<directory>./application/modules/</directory>   
.....
```

For the classloading problem try to take a look at [this](https://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/zendframework-2-centralize-phpunit-test/) article.

Also [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.test.phpunit.html) talk about classloading problem (and solutions) in the comment.

hope this help